# Should I email tech recruiter again after not hearing from him for more than 2 weeks?

Tags: new-job, hiring-process, new-hires, first-job

I reside in Canada and I have applied for a software engineering job in research and development at a well known technology company for which I am really curious and interested. After a couple of days, I have received an email from a recruiter saying that he wanted to discuss a position with me. We scheduled a phone call and he described the position to me and the interview process. He also asked me to send him my resume and student record (I will be graduating in Spring 2023) so that he can send it to some teams at the company as he thought I would be potentially a good candidate for some of them.
I haven't heard from him for more than 2 weeks, should I contact him again? If so, what would be the best approach?
Any suggestions?

Comment: how much exactly is "more than two weeks"?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace BTW :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to start to learn your ways on this Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been answered before. In brief: "Hi, just checking in since I'm very excited about the opportunity to work with you on ____. Please do let me know if you have any further questions for me!'

But be aware that they usually aren't going to make a decision until they see who else is available; 2 weeks is a good time to let them know that you're still available and interested, but an actual decision may take months. Relax, but don't stop interviewing elsewhere until you have a signed contract in hand.

Answer (score 2):

Better than that, call them.

Emails are easier to ignore than Phone Calls. Worst case is something in what you sent through disqualified you from consideration. However even if this is the case, your pro-activeness and initiative may put enough points back in your favor in order to be re-considered.

If they aren't too far away, you could even attempt to visit their office (but that is high risk - some will respect the drive, others will find it a bit creepy)

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't heard from him for more than 2 weeks, should I contact him
> again?

If the choice is contact them, or don't; then in this case you can drop them a quick email.

> If so, what would be the best approach?

It doesn't have to be long. The idea is to remind them that they left you hanging, without telling them that.

But more importantly, keep looking. Apply to things every day. Keep interviewing. There is no reason slow down your search while waiting for somebody to respond to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just ping an email asking them to confirm they received the documents and no more. If they have them they are sent and you are in the queue, or you were rejected and now on his record for a later time, assuming the recruiter is competent.

If you feel there are companies where you would be perfect, apply to all of them.